# Good process specific packet sniffer / viewer?

Tags: process, tcp, udp

I am looking for a good, free or not free, packet sniffer.

The main feature I am looking for is an ability to watch a chosen process and view / read all of the data it is sending or receiving.

Also I want to be able to sniff the connections between local host. (not a must)

I have tried Wireshark, SmartSniff, SocketSniff and they all don't do what I am looking for.

Comment: You can create filters in Wireshark.

Comment: What OS is this for?

Answer (score 2):

Try microsoft network monitor http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148942. It captures raw packets. Additionally it organize packet captures by processes on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

**[CommView](http://www.tamos.com/products/commview/)** is a great packet sniffer. It's not free but has a lot of features, including filtering packets per processes:

> **What you can do with CommView**
>
> - View detailed IP connections statistics: IP addresses, ports, sessions, etc.
> - Reconstruct TCP sessions.
> - ***Map packets to the application that is sending or receiving them.***
> - View protocols distribution, bandwidth utilization, and network nodes charts and tables.
> - Generate traffic reports in real time.
> - Browse captured and decoded packets in real time.
> - Search for strings or hex data in captured packet contents.
> - Import and export packets in Sniffer®, EtherPeek™, AiroPeek™, Observer®, NetMon, and Tcpdump formats, export packets in hex and text formats.
> - Configure alarms that can notify you about important events, such as suspicious packets, high bandwidth utilization, unknown addresses, etc.
> - Create your own plug-ins for decoding any protocol.
> - Exchange data with your application over TCP/IP.
> - Export any IP address to SmartWhois for quick, easy IP lookup.
> - Capture loopback traffic (a new, unique feature in version 4.1).

Comment: Thanks. So far the this was the only product that was able to record the traffic on the local interface. I tried Wireshark and Microsoft Network Monitor tool but none of them worked on the XP machine I was tried to debug. Note: capture and save works with demo version, but the viewer will show you only 50% of the packages :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting requirement.
How about using your favorite capture tool along with `netstat` to trace the local ports and protocol used by the process over the capture time? you could then filter for them later.

example,

```
# with the capture running in the backround, loop over the following
netstat -nt --program | grep firefox
# this will give you a close trace of firefox connections
```

Of course, you will miss those that finish fast between your two `netstst` calls.

Comment: A good idea, but with the scanner running it picks up alot of unwanted packets even with filters.

I am looking for a program like I discribed to see if a suspicious process is sending data to a server and what it is sending while I run it in a sandbox.